# Writing a Tcl extension that will work with multiple versions of Tcl

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2012, tcl, compatibility

At my company we are currently using Tcl 8.4 and we are wanting to update to 8.6. The way we want to do this is by writing all of our new C++ extensions to be compatible with 8.6 and 8.4 so that all the new extensions will work on our old testers that we cannot update to 8.4 because of compatibility issues.

Is there a way to write the code or configure VS 2012 so that the dll will detect the version of Tcl and load the libraries it needs dynamically?

If I use the teapot extension architecture will I attain the same result?

Comment: If you use the Stub mechanism, this should not be necessary.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn perhaps I'm not implementing the stubs correctly. Currently I am defining `USE_TCL_STUBS` in the VS project settings under "C++ Preprocessor Definitions" and including `tclstub84.lib' in the VS project settings under "Linker Input Additional Dependencies". Is there any way that I can do this programmatically rather than through the project settings?

Comment: Did you try to `load` your .dll (build with 8.4) with Tcl 8.6?

Comment: @JohannesKuhn yes i did, and it does work from 8.4 to 8.6. Is there any way you know of to do the opposite? Load a library built in 8.6 into 8.4 so long as you aren't using any methods than do not exist in 8.4. Also, just a side note, the .dll built in 8.4 that loads into 8.6 does not load in 8.5 any idea on that?

Comment: The other direction is totally not supported. Build stub-enabled against the oldest version of Tcl you wish to support, and then you can `load` into later versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see from the comments that you already know how to build libraries that use the stub mechanism.

The stubs mechanism is designed to work in such a way that you can use `load` to bring a DLL into any version of Tcl that is A***B***I-compatible with the version of Tcl that the DLL was built against. Tcl furthermore has **A**pplication **B**inary **I**nterface compatibility rules that mean that *later* versions with the same *major* version number (the “8” in “8.4”) are compatible with earlier versions.

The reverse is not true. 8.4 is not ABI-compatible with 8.6, or at least we don't promise that it is. Even leaving aside the fact that there are additional A***P***I functions in 8.6 that aren't in 8.5 or 8.4, the exact slot in the stub table that is used for a particular function may have moved (automatically-generated C macros manage the forward API compatibility, but those don't cope with reverse compatibility). You should *always* build your extension DLLs against the oldest version of the Tcl API and stub library that you wish to support. (I know of a few people who don't; their code is immensely complex and not at all recommended as an approach.)

**However…**

That is not the only approach you could take. You could also build the library against each version of Tcl that you wish to support, producing a number of DLLs that you give different names, perhaps `mylib84.dll`, `mylib85.dll` and `mylib86.dll`. Then, you group these together into a Tcl package along with a `pkgIndex.tcl` that knows how to load the right one, perhaps like this:

```
if {[package vsatisfies [info tclversion] 8.6]} {
    package ifneeded MyLib 1.0 [list load [file join $dir mylib86.dll]]
} elseif {[package vsatisfies [info tclversion] 8.5]} {
    package ifneeded MyLib 1.0 [list load [file join $dir mylib85.dll]]
} elseif {[package vsatisfies [info tclversion] 8.4]} {
    package ifneeded MyLib 1.0 [list load [file join $dir mylib84.dll]]
}
```

With this scheme, you can even make the versions for 8.5 and 8.4 be not stub-enabled (if that makes sense in your situation). The only downside is that your build process is now more complex: you have to build three versions of the library instead of one.

By making the code into a package and hiding the details of what is going on within that package, you can do very complex things. For example, variations on this mechanism can be used to build single redistributable packages that support multiple architectures; a single download that supports 32-bit Windows, 64-bit Windows and various versions of Linux, so that you can present a set of straight-forward instructions without lots of platform-dependent bits? You can do it with packages, and the cost is just some build complexity, some bandwidth and some disk space…

Comment: This is an extended version of what people were telling you in the comments, plus a possible (if not very pleasant) workaround if you've got problems with using stubs in your case.

Comment: This is a very interesting answer, when you package them in this way will it only produce 1 .dll or will I have to maintain multiple .dll files post build?

Comment: You'd still have multiple DLLs, but you'd put them in the same place (with slightly different names) so managing them post-build wouldn't be too hard. You could then move to packaging them all into a starkit, which would be supported by ActiveTcl and would be a single-file solution. Well, single-file-once-built (which would contain multiple DLLs, but whatever).